# Showing error while inserting User in room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am making an app where I am using room as a database cache and fetching data from the server using retrofit2 and saving it in room database but after fetching from server data is unable to insert in room database.

Here is an exception it is showing:
[image]

This is my pojo class below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users")
public class User {

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("_id")
private String _id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "age")
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;

public User(){}

public User(@NonNull String _id,String name, String age) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

@NonNull
public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(@NonNull String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
[
{
    "id": "5cf68fe7b439470017236249",
    "name": "Rhea",
    "age": "2"
},
{
    "id": "5d09006696a8470cbc7c34a2",
    "name": "Don",
    "age": "10"
},
{
    "id": "5d092d9858af5d22a80858bf",
    "name": "Roman",
    "age": "30"
},
{
    "id": "5d09e9976f3bad18b8fa54a0",
    "name": "Roman",
    "age": "30"
},
{
    "id": "5d09ea2ac127bd07b4b64f6f",
    "name": "Roman",
    "age": "30"
}
]
```

Someone please let me know what is happening wrong. Any hep would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your Json Response. It seems like you are getting _id is null.

Comment: I have posted JSON response.

Comment: change `@SerializedName("_id")`  to `@SerializedName("id")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chnage 

@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("_id") // key does not match with response key
private String _id;


to 


@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@SerializedName("id")
private String _id;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have the id parameter named as "id" in your JSON while your model is waiting for "_id". Try removing that leading underscore symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one or more users id that you are fetching data from the server using retrofit2 is null, and because of that you can't insert into your local database